# Pointer assignment in C++. (Pointer to a pointer to pointer is on the LHS)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers, dereference

```
IDirect3DSurface9 *var = NULL;

IDirect3DSurface9 *** ret;
```

I want to assign the value dereferenced by var into the variable pointed by ret.

I did the foll:

```
(*(*(ret[0]))) = var;
```

I feel this is correct C++ syntax. But why is that I am getting compilation error as follows:

> error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes right hand
>   operand of type "IDirect3DSurface9 *" (or these is no acceptable
>   conversion).

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Can you edit your question to remove all the bold face all caps shouting. You don't need to shout. We can here you fine.

Comment: I edited a bit, but I'm not actually sure about the intended number of asterisks now :-S

Comment: @KerrekSB Gah, every few seconds the number of asterisks keeps changing. I'm deleting my answer!

Comment: @engineerMaster: *Whenever* you want to say "it's a bug with [someone who is not myself]", you're probably wrong. Do try to find fault with *yourself* first and foremost; it's a simple numbers game to work out that that's a more productive approach.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The number of asterisks in the post has remained invariant, but the number of *visible* asterisks may have changed :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes I can see that I was premature in answering.

Comment: **Why** do you have so many pointers? This looks horrible.

Comment: I have edited the code snippet properly now. The confusion was bcoz of the fact that when we select a code snippet and make it a code block it adds some more asterisks.    Finally-> Var has 1 asterisk & ret has 3 asterisks to it. :)

Comment: In case you haven't noticed, your Shift key is broken.

Comment: I apologize everone for all the confusion that happened in initial few minutes of posting the question. Now the code snippet is final. Edited it properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have de-referenced the pointer 3 times. Once when you treated it as an array and used the index `[0]`, and then twice more with the `*` operator. In order to be compatible with `var` you should de-reference only twice.

To be more explicit, let's break this down:

- `ret` has type `IDirect3DSurface9***`.
- `ret[0]` has type `IDirect3DSurface9**`.
- `*(ret[0])` has type `IDirect3DSurface9*`.
- `*(*(ret[0]))` has type `IDirect3DSurface9`.

And clearly it follows that `*(*(ret[0]))` is not assignment compatible with `var` which has type `IDirect3DSurface9*`.

As to what your code really should be, I could not say for sure, but you will need to remove one level of indirection.

Comment: Incredible!!!!  Thank u so much for such a speedy answer!!  I resolved it. :)    I did *(*(ret[0])) = *var;   Now both types LHS & RHS are same. So no compilation error.

Comment: That removes the compilation error but I'm not convinced it is correct. Surely your assignment should be at the `IDirect3DSurface9*` level rather than the `IDirect3DSurface9` level.

Comment: Yes I can change it like *(ret[0]) = var;     But I have the doubt that how does it matter wheather we do the assignment at IDirectX3DSurface9* level or at IDirectX3DSurface9 level. Bcoz finally we are copying the values stored in the variable of tyoe IDirectX3DSurface9 right ? Sorry if I am wrong. Kindly correct me & clarify. Thanks.

Comment: I strongly suspect that your right hand side be `var` rather than `*var` but I can't see the rest of your code.

Comment: @engineerMaster: Don't do that - `IDirect3DSurface9` is a COM interface and has no data members. Your assignment is going to compile but it will also destroy any data that the interface depends on. Only work with pointers to COM interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Every `*` and `[]` takes away one level of indirection.  So in your code

```
(*(*(ret[0]))) = var;
```

the left-hand-side has type `IDirect3DSurface9`, while the right-hand-side has type `IDirect3DSurface9 *`.  The two types are different, that is why you get the compiler error.  You need to fix this by either removing (at least one) `*` from the LHS or add an `&` (address-of operator) to the RHS (to have `&var`).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want:

```
(*(*(ret[0]))) = &var;
```

or

```
*(*(*(ret[0]))) = var;
```